# How to gracefully stop a UDP receiving thread in C# Unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, udp

I want to have a thread open and waiting for incoming UDP packages and when the application closes down I want it to close down the thread gracefully in a controlled way.

My background is that I use UDP to communicate with custom hardware outside unit and would like to have a thread handledning incoming data. But when I close it down it feels wrong to just leave the thread as it's waiting from incoming packages or is it as simple as jut kil the thread? Should I use the timeout parameter set to 1000 ms and then check if I should close down or keep waiting?

How should this be done?

Comment: When a process closes down it means all threads get closed. So if you didn't end any thread and then close the application, you don't need to take care of your threads, they are all part of the process, so all shutted down. Is that what you were afraid of ?

Comment: Not really as I want it to have a close function as I down the road most probably don't want to just hard terminate but stop things going on and then gracefully shut down.